# Modsecurity causing django admin to send empty response

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, mod-security

I am fairly new to using uwsgi, nginx with modsecurity and pagespeed, and django. When I comment out the lines:

```
       ModSecurityEnabled on;
       ModSecurityConfig modsec_includes.conf;
```

in my mysite_nginx.conf I am able to log into the django admin account as expected, but when I enable them, I get

```
my.server.ip.address didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

in my browser when I try to log in. Looking in my nginx error log shows no modsecurity errors. The error it is showing is:

```
2017/01/26 12:08:13 [alert] 3521#0: worker process 8640 exited on signal 11
```

Since everything seems to be working fine when modsecurity is off, presumably the problem is arising here.

Answer (score 0):

- Compile ModSecurity Branch  v3/master (necessary because you need the common core
  libmodsecurity)
- Compile ModSecurity-nginx connector
- Compile nginx  with add-module ModSecurity-nginx
- Clone and configure  OWASP ruleset and config to Nginx

This would work

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/nginx-with-libmodsecurity-and-owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set-on-ubuntu-1604/

Comment: Hyperlinks can change over time and cause the answers to get lost to broken links. If you could summarize the answer from the link in this post it would help future visitors.

Comment: I need more reputation for post more than 2 links, for the full description I need post 4 url (the src repositories). So  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ , follow the link, if someone have doubts contact me.